# $.fn.dataTable.ext.feature.push() is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to overwrite few defaults value for databale js

Below code is working fine

```
  $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        "scrollCollapse": true
    });
```

But i want to make it conditional basis like first checking id of datable

I tried below code

```
 $.fn.dataTableExt.aoFeatures.push({
        "fnInit": function (oSettings) {
            console.log('d');
            return new TableTools({
                "oDTSettings": {
                  "scrollCollapse": true
                }
            });
        },
        "cFeature": "T",
        "sFeature": "TableTools"
    });
```

But not working, I also thought to give try below

```
 $.fn.dataTable.ext.feature.push({
        fnInit: function (settings) {
            console.log(settings);
            var setting = new $.fn.dataTable.Filtering(settings);
            return filter.node(); // input element
        },
        cFeature: 'F'
    });
```

But i found this is not being called.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/tLkjugr6/)

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Create a demo to reproduce the problem, it can be your implementation causing the feature to be not working.

Comment: fiddle added in post

Comment: To use feature you need add it to dom option see https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Comment: If you could check fiddle search.push is working

Comment: If you add dom to DataTable instance you will see console.log

Comment: I have added data table still that is not called.

Comment: Look https://jsfiddle.net/hymdfqas/ alert is shown...

Comment: How can I change scrollCollapse in that function

Comment: I have updated https://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/uob9x3pv/ could you please check once

Comment: A fundamental question what do you want to achieve?